# Select bootstrap language form helper automatically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to select bootstrap form helper language country automatically when the page is ready or loaded, but it never success to achieve what I need .

```
    if(values == "id")
        {
            $('div.bfh-selectbox').attr('data-language',"id_ID");
            $('div.bfh-selectbox').find('input').val("id_ID");
        }
    else
        {
            $('div.bfh-selectbox').attr('data-language',"en_US");
            $('div.bfh-selectbox').find('input').val("en_US");
        }
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-languages" data-language="en_US" data-available="en_US,id_ID" data-flags="true" style="float: left;">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
        <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#" style="height:inherit !important;">
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
            <div role="listbox">
                <ul role="option"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

even thoguh the `data-language` changed dynamically in the `dom`, but the flag in the selected list is still not change.

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this I think you works well!

[Bootstrap Languaje](http://www.freenetmall.com/common/jquery/FormHelpers/docs/country.html)

Comment: still not solve it, can you describe your answer, please.

Comment: adds full code for this functionality in bootply or parade